# aligning 1 image using its coordinate within a rectangle within a larger image

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, emgucv

I have a large image which has an object. I have a code to find the object using emgu match template within the image. Im doing this by drawing a rectangle around the object and using the rectangle coordinates as source image and another template image of the object. The code works and im able to find the object within the rectangle.

But sometimes the object moves within the rectangle, so the COG of the object changes with reference to the cog of rectangle. Im sending the cog to a robot for marking. So, only the cog of the object changes, but the rectangle remains the same. Which causes incorrect marking.

I want that if the COG(XY) of object changes, the rectangle should align with that. How do I do this?

This is how im matching the template.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> templateImage = template_image;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage = Rectangle_ROI;

        using (Image<Gray, float> imgMatch = sourceImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED))
        {
            //imgMatch.ROI = new Rectangle(templateImage.Width, templateImage.Height, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height);

            Point[] MAX_Loc, Min_Loc;
            double[] min, max;
            imgMatch.MinMax(out min, out max, out Min_Loc, out MAX_Loc);

            using (Image<Gray, double> RG_Image = imgMatch.Convert<Gray, double>().Copy())
            {

                if (max[0] > 0.50)
                {
                    Rectangle match = new Rectangle(MAX_Loc[0], templateImage.Size);
                    sourceImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Yellow), 2);

                }

                else
                {
                    Rectangle match = new Rectangle(MAX_Loc[0], templateImage.Size);
                    sourceImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);

                }
            }
            smallresultbox.Image = sourceImage;
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what the purpose it. What is "COG"?

Comment: center of gravity.